# Overriding opacity of backdrop in withStyles doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dialog

I have a StyledDialog using withStyles and I don't know how to override MuiBackdrop-root, so that it will not darken content. What is the proper field name of this class?

```
const StyledDialog = withStyles({
  Backdrop:{
    root:{
      backgroundColor:'transparent'
    },
  },

  paper:{
    padding: 0,
    boxShadow:'none',
    height: 188,
    width:'35%',
    transition:' all 0.8s ease-in-out',
    borderRadius:14
  }
})(Dialog);
```

P.S I know i can use in as a Dialog prop like
 `BackdropProps={{style:{background:'transparent'} }}`
But I'd like to write it in withStyles

Comment: Why not use the `hideBackdrop` prop?

Comment: Yes, good idea, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To override MuiBackdrop-root you should do it like this:

```
const StyledDialog = withStyles({
  root:{
    backgroundColor:'transparent' // Outside of the Backdrop
  },

  paper:{
    padding: 0,
    boxShadow:'none',
    height: 188,
    width:'35%',
    transition:' all 0.8s ease-in-out',
    borderRadius:14
  }
})(Dialog);

// And add the class like this to the component you want to override
<Component classes={{
  root: classes.root,
}} />
```